# Compare two tables and select records based on two conditions - not exists and no match

Tags: sql, match

I have two tables and need to compare based on the first and last name. The scenario is like that name exists in one but not in other. The other scenario is name exists but not matching because of typo error etc. I can get non matching records using NOT EXISTS but how will i display the name thats in table2 also?
My output table should have three columns like below -

SL.No---Not Exists in Table2--- Name in Table2

Any suggestions appreciated.

Arun

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Say i have two tables A & B, i join them using First Name and Last Name. For example First Name is - ABC in both table A and B where as Lastname in Table A is XYZ and Table B is XYW. Here if we do an outer join bringing First Name and Last Name of Table A and Table B, the value from Table B will be shown as NULL in the final output. Instead of NULL i want ABC and XYW to be displayed. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.firstname
, b.firstname
, a.lastname
, b.lastname
, case 
    when a.firstname is null then 'B only'
    when b.firstname is null then 'A only'
    else 'both'
end
from TableA a
full outer join TableB b
    on b.firstname = a.firstname
    and b.lastname = a.lastname
order by coalesce (a.firstname, b.firstname)
, coalesce (a.lastname, b.lastname)
```

Comment: Above query works fine pointing where the data is coming from, whether from table A or B. If i want the actual mismatched data to be shown in the table then how it is possible?

Comment: If mismatched on either table add `where a.firstname is null or b.firstname is null` immediately before the `order by` line.  If just concerned with those in A but not B change `full outer` to `left outer` and add `where b.firstname is null` if just those from B and not A `right outer` and `where a.firstname is null`.